# Databases - Storing numerical value in VARCHAR datatype

Tags: mysql, types, varchar

I am currently working on a project which requires me to store the hemoglobin level recorded as well as blood pressure, before a blood donation... something like '190/80'.. Should I store this in a Varchar as a string or as two separate values for example systolic (INT) 190, diastolic (INT) 80  ? 
Feedback appreciated

Comment: Sometimes the low quality of questions on this site appals me. Do you _really_ need to ask something so elementary?

Comment: @MikeW this is where us,  the small fishes feed.

Comment: Yes granted, it is not the most interesting question.. but what's wrong with asking for feedback from more experienced bodies ? Keep in mind that this site is also a go-to place for students (such as myself). Also I did search before asking the question, but I did not find a relevant answer..

Comment: Nice one @datelligent :-)

Comment: @datelligent Yes I appreciate the fact that you share my same point of view!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my feedback: I would use the two column approach, storing in separate colums systolic and diastolic values for each observation.

At the point of deploying data, or reporting,  just concatenate.

The two column approach helps you on further reporting,  you may be able to summarize data,  say you need to average blood pressure of a population group, average data for a period of time,  or under any given circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your view. I will then move forward with this in mind, and define the fields as suggested. once again, many thanks

Answer (score 3):

They should be two different numeric fields. Otherwise you cannot calculate statistics or change over time for each donor.